# Failed to import bridging header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8, chartboost

I've read a lot of questions and answers that deal with a similar issue, but I have yet to find a solution.  If anyone could shed some light, that would be wonderful.

I created a Swift project and now I want to combine it with some Objective-C. My "failed to import bridging header" only occurs when I attempt to #import my Chartboost.h file.  So, as long as I don't have anything in my bridging header file, Xcode finds it and gives me no issue.  But once I add this:

```
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
```

I get the error along with 38 other errors saying "Swift Compiler Error - Function definition not allowed here".

I've correctly imported my framework.  And my framework search path is correct.  And it's only when I import the Chartboost framework.  UIKit and Foundation work fine.

Here is what I did leading up to the issue....First, I created a new Obj-C file and then clicked "Yes when Xcode gave me a pop-up asking if it could configure a bridging header.   This created "FunFacts-Bridging-Header.h"

Then I made sure Objective-C Bridging Header path was correct under Swift Compiler - Code Generation.

I even put in a very specific path /Users/me/Desktop/FunFacts/FunFacts-Bridging-Header.h
and it still says "Failed to import".

I've also set Defines Module to "Yes" (because I heard that may help).  And my product module name is FunFacts.

Why is FunFacts-Bridging-Header.h failing to import when I try to add #import ?

Comment: Just as an additional note: apparently, diagnosis of errors that really originate inside the headers to be `#import`ed can be silently absorbed by this single error message about failing to import the bridging header. The real causes become “hidden”. FWIW, some innocuously looking leftoverts of editing in the header were causing Objective-C errors in my case, and I learned this only after running `$ clang -x objective-c -c HeaderWithSyntaxError.h` on the command line, separately.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out 2 solutions!

1)  This isn't the prettiest way to do it, but I copy and pasted all my code from my Chartboost.h file into my Bridging-Header.h file instead of importing .  This worked.  But I knew there was a better way, so I kept hunting...

2)  The correct solution, I believe, is what I did next.  My project's (not target) Framework Search Paths was empty.  So, I went ahead and added the path to the Chartboost SDK like so: /Users/me/Desktop/Apps/SDKs/Chartboost
Now it builds and runs with no problem and I didn't have to copy and paste everything into the bridging header.  All that was needed was

```
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
```

If anyone is having a similar issue, just read what I did in my question, and then follow it up with this answer.

Comment: @Alam_s I have a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322891/how-to-integrate-chartboost-ios-sdk-with-swift but I dont want to "copy and paste all my code from my Chartboost.h file into my Bridging-Header.h file". Also the other solution does not seem to work for me. I have added the Framework search path http://i.imgur.com/PTzcidI.png, http://i.imgur.com/HRwILjd.png yet it still does not work!

Comment: Add to your Framework search path exactly where Chartboost.framework is located on your computer.  Try that.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. I also tried copying the contents of the `Chartboost.h` file into my bridging header file although it did not work either!

Comment: See [quick solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s/34046677#34046677)

Answer (score 41):

I answered this in another post: [Chartboost integration issues with XCode 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961687/chartboost-integration-issues-with-xcode-6-1/27473318#27473318)

#### EXPLANATION:

It seems like some pods and libraries don't bother importing the basic frameworks as they expect your code to already have them. This doesn't work with Swift as the way to import frameworks changed.
All you need to do is to add the frameworks needed in your bridging header file.

#### ANSWER:

**It depends on what errors the compiler throws.
If it complains about `NSObject`, `NSString`, etc... you need to add
`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` in the top of your bridging header file.**

**If it complains about `UIView`, `UIButton`, etc... you need to add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in the top of your bridging header file.**

Answer (score 9):

Had a nearly identical issue and found a solution that worked for me.

My problem was that the Bridging Header was not in ALL my targets.

[image: Project Bridging Header]

---

It was in my project but not my UnitTest target.  So I added it to by my UITest and UnitTest and it started working without issue.

[image: Testing Target]

---

Answer (score 6):

The problem like your's puzzled me.
But I found a solution.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

You should put this code (↑) before your code.
This is just my solution (↓).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
```

Good luck!

Comment: THIS WORKED - can't believe it but it did.  I just made sure everywhere Chartboost was imported, Foundation came first.  You would think Chartboost might mention this???

Answer (score 6):

### This is how I solved it (and works!):

1. Create yourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h file at the root of your project
2. Include in that file the .h of the classes you want to expose and use into your swift project
3. Go to yourProject->Build Settings->Search Paths, and set to Yes the "Always Search User Paths" key.
4. Set "User Header Search Paths" to your project root path.

That's it.

Apparently, Xcode miss out on third party folders when they are copied into your project

I am on Xcode 6.3 , swift 1.2.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is really very simple.

Make sure you are adding your bridging header path in SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER under the target section instead of the project section.

Comment: Please include an explanation as to why this answer solves the asker's question.

Comment: yes close xcode and the problem appears again. 'the most advanced technology company' circa 2016

Answer (score 4):

If you use CocoaPods this could save your time.
1) The first what you need to do is to check your Podfile it will be like:

```
target 'YourProjTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
end

target 'YourProjUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
end
```

2) Open baseproj configuration and set for test targets correct Pods-Proj.debug , see attached image:[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have these lines in you bridging header:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

Just delete them, it will solve the problems of Foundation and UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

One case is that if `import <Chartboost+Extention/Chartboost+Extention.h>` ,

The right way is to `import <Chartboost**_**Extention/Chartboost+Extention.h>` ,

Just because Pod build will change the framework name of `Chartboost+Extention` into `Chartboost_Extention`