# How to integrate Chartboost IOS SDK with Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, chartboost

I am trying to integrate the Chartboost IOS SDK with Swift. I have followed all the instructions on the Chartboost IOS Integration page https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201220095-iOS-Integration and have created a bridging header to use the framework in my swift project.

**BridgingHeader.h**

```
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
#import <Chartboost/CBNewsfeed.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
```

My BridgingHeader.h file is loacated in my project root directory https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl6kY.png and I have followed the necessary steps to add the BridgingHeader.h to my Build Settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM4Tq.png but when I run the project I get 52 errors like -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZjRI.png. Why am I getting these errors and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the headers require UIKit and Foundation. Add this line at the top of your bridging header.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Also, have you made sure your bridging header is in the project's root in the file system? The hierarchy of Xcode's Project Navigator isn't necessarily the same as the file system.

It's looking for the header in `/Users/andrew/Documents/dev/ios/Protect Paigridge/` Open finder and make sure that the header is in that directory. Xcode may have created it a level deeper where the rest of your code files are. If that's the case, you can edit entry in Build Settings or move the file.

Comment: Just checked and my `BridgingHeader.h` file is definitely in `/Users/andrew/Documents/dev/ios/Protect Paigridge/`

Comment: Sorry but I have not tried yet. The reason is because I develop on the family iPad and my parents have gone for a couple of nights and took it with them. I was planing on trying once they got back but will just use an emulator. Sorry for keeping you waiting!

Comment: We have progress! I'm not getting all the errors anymore, although I am getting a different one in my swift code http://imgur.com/Zz4ryXl. Would you be able to assist with this?

Comment: Do you need that line? It looks like I have access to all the Chartboost methods without importing it.

Comment: Turns out I did not. Sorry for that, I am new to making IOS apps. I just want to say, you are a wizard! Cheers.

Comment: This is a great answer. If this solves most of your problems except a few try also adding #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> above the import chartboost.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You still need " #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  " in bridging class even you already import UIKit in your swift class. That is work for me.

Comment: Hey- would someone here look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919940/chartboost-with-swift-interstitial-prefetch-if-not-complete-wait-but-no-a Im having problems with Swift and Chartboost

Answer (score 0):

Swift Chartboost Code, Add it in AppDelegate Class :

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) 
{        
    let kChartboostAppID = "5472ef8f04b01601a1a5814c";
    let kChartboostAppSignature = "5b6222426e68cda48669a1d4d8246d4c3d20db9c";

    Chartboost.startWithAppId(kChartboostAppID, appSignature: kChartboostAppSignature, delegate: self);
    Chartboost.cacheMoreApps(CBLocationHomeScreen)
}

class func showChartboostAds()
{
     Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen);
}

func didFailToLoadInterstitial(location :String!, withError error: CBLoadError)
{

}

func didDismissInterstitial(location :String! )
{
        if(location == CBLocationHomeScreen)
        {
            Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationMainMenu)
        }
        else if(location == CBLocationMainMenu)
        {
            Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationGameOver)
        }
        else if(location == CBLocationGameOver)
        {
            Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationLevelComplete)
        }
        else if(location == CBLocationLevelComplete)
        {
            Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen)
        }
 }
```

Calling Syntax:

```
   AppDelegate.showChartboostAds()
```

Comment: Do you really want to post your app ID/signature publicly on stack overflow?

Comment: Hey - I'm having an odd issue here would you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919940/chartboost-with-swift-interstitial-prefetch-if-not-complete-wait-but-no-a

Answer (score 0):

This issue is how to import.

You can make objC code and bridge.h, to shows in your code

`[Chartboost showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];`

For swift

`Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen)`

i wish that help you

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the top answer said above try adding both

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
```

to your BridgingHeader.h File

and make sure they are both above the

```
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
```

as shown above