# Chartboost with Swift - Interstitial: prefetch if NOT complete. wait... but no ad?

Tags: swift, chartboost

I am trying to integrate Chartboost ads in Swift into my project and have followed the tutorial verbatim:

https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/205853276

Everything is imported and in App delegate I have:

```
Chartboost.startWithAppId(//stuff)
        Chartboost.setShouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession(false)
        Chartboost.cacheMoreApps(CBLocationHomeScreen)

//Chartboost

class func showChartboostAds()
{
    Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen);
}

func didFailToLoadInterstitial(location :String!, withError error: CBLoadError)
{

}

func didDismissInterstitial(location :String! )
{
    if(location == CBLocationHomeScreen)
    {
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationMainMenu)
    }
    else if(location == CBLocationMainMenu)
    {
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationGameOver)
    }
    else if(location == CBLocationGameOver)
    {
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationLevelComplete)
    }
    else if(location == CBLocationLevelComplete)
    {
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocationHomeScreen)
    }
}
```

Then in my main view controlleR:

```
AppDelegate.showChartboostAds()
```

I have my app in test mode in the dashboard and am running on a real device but I just get  Interstitial: prefetch if NOT complete. wait...  in the console.

Why won't it show any ads?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?  I am having this problem

Comment: No. Glad to have company.

Comment: Join this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120912/cberror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to show the AD to quickly.  Try delaying the AD, that solved it for me.

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just an aside, the reason this solution works is because of the prefetch method. It seems when you call the ad the Chartboost prefetch isn't completing on time, which is causing the show call to fail.

Chartboost does have a delegate method that will give you the all-clear when prefetch completes, that may be worth a look: - (void)didPrefetchVideos;

[Here's a link](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201219455-Delegate-Methods-iOS) to the rest of the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  Really great input!