# Import Header Error Swift when relaunching app

Tags: ios, swift, header

I imported a header file to a swift project.
The header file contained inputs to Parse obj c libraries.
Everything worked fine I tested with Parse no problem.

When I saved then closed the project then re-opned I get a compiler error saying the Header file cannot be found. Here is the error.

> failed to import bridging header '/Users/callanmooneys/Desktop/iOS
>   Deveolpment/Swit/Lab cases Haematology/Lab Maternity Haematology/Lab
>   Maternity Haematology-Bridging-Header.h'

Tried everything here:

[Swift Bridging Header import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue)

I don't understand how all worked fine until I saved the project the re-opened it.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also try:

- cleaning the build folder using Shift-CMD-Option-K
- check the build settings to be sure that the correct bridging header with correct path is selected
- deleting the bridging header, but only deleting the reference. Then, quit XCode and on relaunch, re-add your bridging header to your project
- creating a Objective-C header, copying the code of your old header in there, and then setting the new header as your bridging header in project settings

EDIT:

- try saving the file without spaces

Comment: @dancingbush hm, try saving the file with a name that doesn't include spaces?

Comment: Xcode seems to add the project name automatically to the header file, and the project name does have spaces...

Comment: Maybe save the project without spaces?

Comment: I have a feeling u mat be right, but does this mean i have to rename my project so it has no spaces? Or can the project name be different form the name that appears on the app store..

Comment: @dancingbush yes, the name can be different as far as I know. 

Comment: Cheers. I started another project from scratch this time WITHOUT a space in project title and everything works fine, is this a bug we should report to Apple? What a headache

Comment: @dancingbush great! Glad to know it helped! Sure, file a radar, that can always help.

Answer (score 1):

Even if Swift isn't in beta anymore, there are still some bugs. So you should try several things.

- [Delete derived Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6)
- Clean your Project: `Product -> Clean`
- [Edit the search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116288/failed-to-import-bridging-header) (First answer)
- Check that your `.h` file etc is still available and you didn't delete it by mistake.

Comment: Tried deleting derived data, cleaned (its cleans but when I build same errors), .h file is present, check the file inspector for header file and libraries the path seem correct (is tis what u mean by edit search path?)

Comment: Every time I delete references from the Parse and Bolt frameworks and move the packages to the trash from the project, re copy them over everything works fine, but as soon as i close and re open the project i get this same error!

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening to me whenever I use an Obj-C Bridging Header in any of my projects.

Whenever I launch, I get the same error, along with another one that goes something like:

```
Parse/Parse.h file not found
```

Every time I launch Xcode, I delete the Parse.framework from my Xcode project completely, then drag it back in. 
This fixes the issue for me until I quit Xcode, and then I will repeat upon relaunch.

This has been happening to me for many months, not only with Parse, but it's also happened with RevMobAds.framework. I've gotten used to deleting and reinstalling the frameworks each launch.

Comment: Same, funny though I did note this does not seem to occur if project title has no spaces, but will your app run when deployed to app store?

Comment: That is quite interesting. All the projects that this has been happening with do indeed have spaces in the project name. But to your question, I have successfully submitted an app to the app store while this problem was occurring (this was with the RevMobAds framework) and everything went fine, and the ads are showing up on the app.

Comment: Cheers, see below comments I just started a new project with a project name without spaces, I plan to change the name as it appears on App store to a name with spaces (assuming this is possible)