# MZAppearance/MZAppearance.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use this library https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetPresentationController in swift But I am getting this error

```
/Users/myname/Downloads/MZFormSheetPresentationController-master/MZFormSheetPresentationController/MZFormSheetPresentationController.h:27:9: error: 'MZAppearance/MZAppearance.h' file not found
#import <MZAppearance/MZAppearance.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/myname/Downloads/MZFormSheetPresentationController-master/MZFormSheetPresentationController/MZFormSheetPresentationController Swift Example-Bridging-Header.h'
```

**Update**

I have downloaded MZAppearance separately from here https://github.com/m1entus/MZAppearance
 but still error is coming

[image]

Comment: Check this : [Failed to import bridging header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116288/failed-to-import-bridging-header#answer-27473376)

Comment: Please show your project directory structure and the relevant include path settings.

Comment: @JanGreve HOW ? do you want me to send you the navigator screenshot ?

Comment: Hi did you solved it? I have same problem

Comment: Im using cocoa pod install and Im getting the same error as you, I just verified and i have MZAppearance also in the Pods installed .. very strange isssue but is killing me

Comment: Did you solved it @hellosheikh