# Failed to import bridging header file - Swift

Tags: swift, bridging-header

I'm trying to import my bridging header file but it does not work, I have used all the solution introduced here [Failed to import bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116288/failed-to-import-bridging-header)

but nothing worked for me.

I'm trying to import this library from github, can someone please help

https://github.com/nst/STTwitter

this is the error

```
       ^
/Users/aftheer/Downloads/STTwitter-master 5/STTwitter/STHTTPRequest+STTwitter.h:9:9: error: 'STHTTPRequest.h' file not found
#import "STHTTPRequest.h"
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/aftheer/Desktop/twitterApp/twitterApp/twitterApp-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: SSTwitter uses cocoapods to install it. Are you working in the workspace? (not the xcodeproj)

Comment: I'm not working with cocoapods

Comment: Ah, okay. Looks like the STTwitter library is in your Downloads folder, not actually in your project. I would try removing the reference from your project, cleaning the project (product > clean), drag it back in and have it copy to your project this time.

Comment: sorry but how can I remove the refrence?

Comment: Right click on it in Xcode > delete > remove reference (not move to trash).

Comment: Right-click on the file in the Xcode file navigator (the left pane), select **Delete**. A dialog will pop up asking whether you'd like to remove the reference to the file, or delete the file from the file system.

Comment: thank you but this did not solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

```
#import <STTwitter/STTwitter.h>
```

You have to use "<", ">", and the framework-name. This one worked for GoogleSignIn:

```
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
```

Comment: Worked for me...Thank you so much..Was stuck in here for hours :(