# Xcode is ignoring the bridging header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

Using Xcode 9 and Swift 4, I created a bridging header file in order to utilize an external framework but no matter what I do, Xcode ignores the bridging header file. I followed the steps that I found online and I don't what's wrong with the project. I attached an image, shouldn't this give me a compilation error since there are invalid characters in the header file?

[Click to see Xcode project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRspW.png)

This is not a duplicate question, that question that was suggested has issues making the header file work because of compile errors, in my situation compilation is successful and Xcode doesn't even try to compile the header file.

I created another project from scratch and I was able to make the bridging header work so I guess there is something wrong with this project. I create this project and try again.

Comment: do you want to see the errors or bridge your project ? Have you tried to import your libs to see if it works ?

Comment: Try to clear the Derived data, clean project, close xCode, launch again

Comment: Cleared the Derived data, cleaned project and restarted Xcode, build succeeds even the bridge file has bad content. When I add the proper import into the bridging header, I can't use it in Swift, it says undeclared type, that's why I got the idea that Xcode doesn't use the bridging file at all for some reason. Another thing I tried was, I changed the file in Build Settings to broken path, Xcode still succeeds the build.

Comment: Is your bridging header automatically generated by Xcode, or did you create your own?

Comment: I tried both ways, automatic and manual, the result has been the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to import bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116288/failed-to-import-bridging-header)

Answer (score 3):

I found out that creating objective-c file instead of directly creating header file is more convenient.

You can try to create a dummy `objective-c` file.

From Xcode's file menu click `File`-> `New`-> `File`. Choose `Objective-C File` and click `next` button.

You can give any dummy name you want. I gave the name as `DummyFile`.

[image: new objective-c files]

Click `Next`.

Now save this file in the project's directory.

As Xcode is about to add this `Objective-C` file to your `Swift` project is automatically asks you to create a `Bridging Header` as shown below.

[[image: Xcode's bridging header creation option[2]]

As you click `Create Bridging Header`, Xcode creates a `Brigder-Bridging-Header.h` file (As my project name is "Bridger") and put it in the project's directory as shown in Xcode's project navigation pan.

[image: Bridging header file].

Now you can import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.

You can now delete the `DummyFile.m` from the project's directory if you want.

And this should work as wished.

Answer (score 2):

```
Project > Build Settings > SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER
```

Have you specified the Bridging header file name here?

Comment: I just added to Project -> Build Settings as well as Target -> Build Settings, cleaned the project and the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

As Biju said, specify Bridging header file name - try changing its location (e.g. put it inside project folder)

Answer (score 0):

Perform a clean build by cleaning first (Command + K) and then Building (Command + B).

Had the same issue and this fixed it.